# Is there a "FlashBag" for offline users?

Tags: symfony

I've a command that runs in the background every night.

I'd like to notify my users if such command fails in the middle of something as soon as they log in the following morning.

Does symfony provide a similar "FlashBag" for that?

I know that FlashBag uses sessions, so it won't work for offline users.

My idea is to use a "Notifications" table, and as soon as they log in display them the most recent notifications.

However, I figured that probably symfony already provides a similar functionality or there's a bundle for it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notifications table idea seems to be the right approach based on your description. Now, depending on how you're designing your system, you may need to store the last_login timestamp of every user, and then only retrieve notifications that have happened since the last_login timestamp. May also need to do some special actions for users that are already logged in.

As for packages that already offer some of the functionality, this is the only bundle that's still supported that I could find on KNP Bundles:

http://knpbundles.com/synthmedia/SynthNotificationBundle

I also found this bundle with a lot of upvotes, but it's not maintained any more:

https://github.com/merk/merkNotificationBundle